# Saving an Excel file via OLE automation forces a password

Tags: excel, delphi, ole

I create, fill and save an Excel file via OLE automation in Delphi.
When saving it, a password is automatically added to the file ("0").

```
FexclplctnXLApp.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs(
    FAvailSaveName, xlWorkbookDefault, 
    varEmpty,varEmpty, varEmpty, varEmpty, varEmpty, varEmpty,
    varEmpty, varEmpty, varEmpty, varEmpty, lcid);
```

VarEmpty seems to be the issue here, it's value is "0".
I tried also with '', with the same result.

Comment: This has never happened to me automating Excel with Delphi for the last decade. Please post a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue (meaning it can be copied, pasted, compiled, and run with minimal changes).

Comment: What @KenWhite says.  Which version of Delphi and which Excel import unit are you using?

Comment: Btw, it is trivial to clear the password on an .Xls file by using a late-bound call to `SaveAs` and specifying a blank password, as in `vWorkbook := WorkBook; vWorkBook.SaveAs(FileName := 'SomeWorkBook', PassWord := '')`, vWorkBook being an OleVariant.

Answer (score 3):

The right parameter is `EmptyParam`. You need to specify an 'empty' variant for optional parameters that you don't want to give a value. You could use any variant for that, but `EmptyParam` is declared globally as an empty variant for this purpose.

You are using `varEmpty`, which is a numeric constant representing the type of such an empty variant. `varEmpty` indeed has the value `0`, which, for a password will be interpreted as a string. See [`varEmpty` constant](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/System_varEmpty.html).

Comment: Yes indeed the EmptyParam was the solution.
Tnx.